# Minimum spanning tree using BFS

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree

In finding a minimum spanning tree, if we use a BFS and at any node instead of deleting the edge to a repeated node, we can find the most expensive node in that cycle instead and delete it.
In such a case, will the time complexity remain O(E+V)?

Comment: What did you try?  Where are you stuck? Did you try to write the pseudocode for the algorithm and analyse it?